# How to setup and open Sublime Text from Bash command line?

Tags: windows, bash

I'm having trouble setting up Sublime Text for bash on Windows Powershell. I would like to use Sublime Text instead of emacs or vi. I got it to work once but every time I close the terminal it stops working.

I used

```
alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"'
```

and this works but after I close the terminal and reopen it, it does not recognize the command anymore.

Comment: You should add it to some profile file. I'm not sure how you do it in Powershell (should be equivalent to `.bashrc`).

Comment: You mention both Bash and PowerShell; the command in your question is a Bash `alias` command - how does PowerShell come into play here? Please clarify by updating your question directly.

Comment: Removed the [tag:powershell] and [tag:emacs] tags which seemed completely out of place here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `bash.exe` either from the powershell or calling `bash.exe` directly, windows doesn't appear to make your default directory your home! Thats maybe why perhaps you cannot see `.bashrc` as other have mentioned. So in order to make your alias persistent..

Move to your home direcotry:

```
cd ~
vim .bash_profile
```

I use `.bash_profile` but as others have mentioned you could/can add it to `.bashrc`

Add this into your `.bash_profile`:

```
alias subl=' "/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"'
```

Now every time you login, `.bash_profile` will load and in turn your alias

```
subl
```

Will see Sublime text load for you

I would recommend a slightly clener way. Add this to your `.bash_profile` instead:

```
export PATH="/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3":$PATH
```

Now you can simply just run:

```
sublime_text.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

in WIN 10
do 
WIN + pause 
select Advanced settings

[select Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb2zb.png) 
[add the path to sublime to the env variable list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLxkY.png)